# Oracle: how to prevent from re-entering existing id ?

Tags: oracle10g

I've a column for inserting ID *which is not declared as primary key but I've to prevent dublicate entry of any ID.*
**how to find if a ID has already been inserted in the oracle database or not?? If the ID is already present in db, the user can not re-enter the ID.**
How can I do it??

Comment: Any reason you cannot create a unique index on the column? That would be the most reliable (only?) way to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Have you considered using an Oracle SEQUENCE object to generate unique ID values? A SEQUENCE can be referenced in a BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW trigger, to set the value of the id column. That's about as close as you are going to get for a guarantee (as long as no one mucks with the the SEQUENCE object or trigger), without adding a UNIQUE constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a unique constraint on the column.

Comment: +1 That would be the most reliable (only?) way to prevent duplicates.

Comment: isn't there any other way of doing it??

Comment: @sam = What is the downside in your mind to using a constraint?  They are more efficient.  They involve writing and maintaining less code.  They work in multi-user systems.

Comment: @sam: no, there is no other way of providing a guarantee.  You can write your INSERT statement to do a check `INSERT INTO mytable (id) SELECT 1234 FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE ID = 1234)`, but that doesn't provide a guarantee that duplicates won't be added concurrently.